# How to fix my counter which increments each time a certain # is selected?

Tags: java, if-statement, random, counter

I am working on a guessing game assignment. The computer randomizes 3 letters from R/B/G/Y and the user tries to guess the correct order and position of the combination. A counter is incremented to give hints, ie. count how many letters and/or positions the user gets right with each guess until they narrow it down.

This is my method that randomizes the computer's combo:

```
public static void newGame(){
// Randomize colour choice (# between 1 and 4)
col1 = (int)(Math.random()*4)+1;
col2 = (int)(Math.random()*4)+1;
col3 = (int)(Math.random()*4)+1;

switch ((int)col1){
    case 1: ans1 = ("R");
        break;
    case 2: ans1 = ("G");
        break;
    case 3: ans1 = ("B");
        break;
    case 4: ans1 = ("Y");
        break;
}
switch ((int)col2){
    case 1: ans2 = ("R");
        break;
    case 2: ans2 = ("G");
        break;
    case 3: ans2 = ("B");
        break;
    case 4: ans2 = ("Y");
        break;
}
switch ((int)col3){
    case 1: ans3 = ("R");
        break;
    case 2: ans3 = ("G");
        break;
    case 3: ans3 = ("B");
        break;
    case 4: ans3 = ("Y");
        break;
}
colchoice = ans1 + " " + ans2 + " " + ans3;

}//end newGame method
```

These are my counter methods:

```
public static void checkColoursCorrect(){
inputnumber(guess1,guess2,guess3);
// Determine how many user inputted letters equal the randomized ones
correctc = 0;
if (uguess1 == col1 || uguess1 == col2 || uguess1 == col3){
    correctc++;
}
if (uguess2 == col1 || uguess2 == col2 || uguess2 == col3){
    correctc++;
}
if (uguess3 == col1 || uguess3 == col2 || uguess3 == col3){
    correctc++;
}
}//end checkColoursCorrect method

public static void checkPositionsCorrect(){
inputnumber(guess1,guess2,guess3);
correctp = 0;
if (uguess1 == col1){
    correctp++;
}
if (uguess2 == col2){
    correctp++;
}
if (uguess3 == col3){
    correctp++;
}
if (uguess1 == col1 && uguess2 == col2 && uguess3 == col3){
    System.out.println("User wins! Colour was " + colchoice);
}
}//end checkPositionsCorrect method
```

I think that, since the combo is randomized, each time the counter methods call col1/col2/col3, a NEW combo is used rather than the one initialized in the first place? If anyone could point me in the direction on how to fix this it would be appreciated.

Input number method:

```
public static void inputnumber(String guess1, String guess2, String guess3){
// Convert user's FIRST guess to a number
if ("R".equals(guess1)){
    uguess1 = 1;
}
if ("G".equals(guess1)){
    uguess1 = 2;
}
if ("B".equals(guess1)){
    uguess1 = 3;
}
if ("Y".equals(guess1)){
    uguess1 = 4;
}

// Convert user's SECOND guess to a number
if ("R".equals(guess2)){
    uguess2 = 1;
}
if ("G".equals(guess2)){
    uguess2 = 2;
}
if ("B".equals(guess2)){
    uguess2 = 3;
}
if ("Y".equals(guess2)){
    uguess2 = 4;
}

// Convert user's FINAL guess to a number
if ("R".equals(guess3)){
    uguess3 = 1;
}
if ("G".equals(guess3)){
    uguess3 = 2;
}
if ("B".equals(guess3)){
    uguess3 = 3;
}
if ("Y".equals(guess3)){
    uguess3 = 4;
}
}
```

Comment: could you provide the inputnumber method ...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, in first lines of your code you want to get random values for col1, col2 and col3.
I think Java may probably have same attitude as C, so you need to create a random number generator in your code in order to get new random numbers every time you run your program. Otherwise you will only get random numbers once, at time of compilation.
At this [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) you can see Oracle's documentation for class Random. You probably need to create a generator (using new Random()) and then newInt() to get random int values later in the code.

When you notice concurrent modification, making sure you do not access same fields from different methods is number one to be checked.

Comment: That's not my issue... my issue is that the random numbers change when I call the counter methods -- they are not supposed to so that my counter reflects the results accurately.

Comment: I am quite sure that if you tried the method I wrote about it shall work. They would only be generated when you call nextInt().

Comment: ? I already HAVE a random number generator. It's the Math.random() class that is in my method newGame(). I don't really understand what you're suggesting. My issue is not with my random numbers, it is with my counters.

Comment: From what you are saying I understand that when you call any of your counter methods, numbers col1...3 are different than before, am I wrong?

Comment: If you do not call method newGame() anywhere along the way before calling counter methods, you shouldn't get any new value. (tell me if I am wrong with that). I suggest you should build a Random generator, and then call method nextInt() in your newGame() and then see if it works. Math.random() gives you a double from (0,1), so why use it and then multiply the number instead of just generating an int from the desired interval?

Comment: No, I call newGame() in the main method, which also calls the counter methods after. I don't really want to include things that are not in my course content ("random generator"). The assignments are supposed to be coded with everything I have learned up to that point.

Comment: Are you sure you do not access fields col1..3 anywhere between newGame() and counter methods?

Comment: Oh yeah, I do. Does that make a difference? I use the same variables for the computer player, who is facing against the user to determine who guesses the combo first. The computer player's answers are also randomly generated with the same variables. But because they are in different methods I thought it would be ok.

Comment: That changes the whole point I guess. If your computer player also randomizes col1...3 they will be changed, as they are the fields of your class. Because of that, they are accessible from every method within this class, and as they are passed to methods by reference (as everything in Java) they get changed. Variables col1, col2 and col3 are (as it appears) fields of your class, they are not boxed within any of the methods.

Comment: OH WOW, THANK YOU. I just changed the computer player's variables and it works! Wow, I spent five hours looking over that code! Ugh. But thank you for pointing that out! I wouldn't have guessed that myself. My program works great now. Thanks again!